# Is there an archive of older Linux kernels from the tumbleweed repo?

Tags: kernel, archive, suse, tumbleweed

I need to narrow in on what kernel version a change was introduced in the tumbleweed kernels. Any kernels between 4.4 and 4.10 would be useful.

Is there an archive of these kernels kept somewhere?

I would prefer to avoid having to build from source if possible.

Answer (score 4):

To view all the kernels available in your enabled repositories you can run this command:

`zypper se -s kernel-default`

Some of my output is like this for example:

```
S | Name                 | Type       | Version       | Arch   | 
Repository            
--+----------------------+------------+---------------+--------+---------
--------------
i | kernel-default       | package    | 4.4.57-18.3.1 | x86_64 | Main Update Repository
v | kernel-default       | package    | 4.4.49-16.1   | x86_64 | Main Update Repository
v | kernel-default       | package    | 4.4.46-11.1   | x86_64 | Main Update Repository
i | kernel-default       | package    | 4.4.36-8.1    | x86_64 | Main Update Repository
v | kernel-default       | package    | 4.4.36-5.1    | x86_64 | Main Update Repository
v | kernel-default       | package    | 4.4.27-2.1    | x86_64 | Main Repository (OSS)
```

After that it depends on if you just want the package or if you want to install it to your system. To install it to your system run the command like this:

`zypper in --oldpackage kernel-default-<version number>`

If you just want to download the rpm you can run it like this:

`zypper in --download-only --oldpackage kernel-default-<version number>`

It will download the rpm package into the `/var/cache/zypp/packages/` directory. From there it's divided by repository. You can see in the earlier output that the last column says what repository it is from. You can use that to help you identify which directory to search for the package.

The above only provides the regular kernel-default and kernel-default-base packages. If you are wanting to get the packages with source code you'll have to make sure your debug repositories are enabled.

So for example, on my SUSE Leap 42.2 I use `zypper lr` to see that the `openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Debug` and `openSUSE-Leap-42.2-Update-Debug` repositories are repository numbers 13 and 15. So I run these commands to enable and then refresh them:

```
zypper mr -e 13 15
zypper ref -s
```

After that the `zypper se -s kernel-default` command I provided earlier will also include the `kernel-default-debuginfo` packages as well as the `kernel-default-debugsource` packages. You could then download the source code package with the same command as before:

```
zypper in --download-only --oldpackage kernel-default-debugsource-<version-number>
```

You'd then check the corresponding repository directory in the `/var/cache/zypp/packages/` directory for the package. In my case it was in the following location:

```
/var/cache/zypp/packages/repo-debug/suse/x86_64/kernel-default-debugsource-4.4.27-2.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to directly use the git repo of openSUSE: [openSUSE/kernel-source](https://github.com/openSUSE/kernel-source), the config files for x86_64 is under config/x86_64, usually the flavor "default" is chosen.

You can browse all the tags, then use the tag needed to get the config file of specific version needed by you.